# How to stream text to the browser in ASP.net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, streaming

I'm trying to figure out how to make ASP.net MVC 4 send data back to the browser during a long-running operation.  Because I've never done this before, I am starting with a simple example:

```
public void Index()
{
    Response.Write("<p>Hello, world! Counting to 5!</p>");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Response.Write("<p>" + i + "</p>");
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

I would think that this code should immediately send "Hello, world! Counting to 5!" to the browser and then send one digit per second afterwards until it reaches five.

However, when I run this code, it takes five seconds and all the text is output at once.

I thought that the Response.Flush() method was supposed to allow you to send data to the browser incrementally.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

First of all, it appears that Internet Explorer won't stream text if it doesn't see that the document is valid HTML.  I added code to print out a barebones HTML page around my data and that seems to have made it work.

Another author writes here: http://encosia.com/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/ that Internet Explorer will automatically buffer the first 256 characters of input, and so recommends putting in 256 characters of throw-away data at the beginning, but that doesn't seem to make a difference in the version I'm working with (IE 10).

Finally, I only counted to four because I was off by one ;-)

Here's my working code:

```
public void Index()
{
    Response.Write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>");

    Response.Write("<!--");
    Response.Write(new string('*', 256));            
    Response.Write("-->");
    Response.Flush();

    Response.Write("<p>Hello, world! Counting to 5!</p>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Write("<p>" + i + "</p>");                
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
        Response.Write("</body></html>");
}
```